# Generate a multi-select option on a form using a junction table -> web2py

Tags: python, database, web2py

I have two tables with a many-to-many relationship between them. One table holds types of properties, the other holds regions.

For the sake of simplicity let's say it goes something like this:

```
_property_
id
name
description

_region_
id
name

_property-region_
id
property.id
region.id
```

I want to build a form to create new properties, and I want this form to contain a multi-select option allowing the user to specify which region/s the property is available in.

I understand that I can create a multi-select form using `list:reference` without actually creating a junction table, but I would be interested in learning how to do this without de-normalising the database.

Answer (score 0):

its not denoramalising?
each region can have many properties and relation is held by region...
on the query level you just ask for regions which hold the id of the property... (either way you have to query db for that even if you have junction/through table)

If you have specific info about relation, you have to process that logic yourself. Aint that hard,
create two forms validate property info and the record will be in database thus you posess the id. Then just add that id as one part of relation and all the selected items as other.

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't describe my question very well. The suggested  table structure isn't after denormalisation. When I mentioned denormalising, it's when using list:reference in web2py.

Comment: Its not denormalisation?
Only one party holds the references... if you create the field on both models then you have it denormalized.

Comment: Thanks for replying Markek. Do you know what list:reference does in web2py? Perhaps check it out?

Comment: its pretty standard list, web2py interprets it and through you can access those items.